# Solution Cloning happening at steps that produce a "new best score" in a row

Tags: optaplanner

Something that recently caught my attention was a step being slower than others when a "new best score" is produced. This is definitely the solution cloning that is happening at every step that produces a "new best score".

So this is okay if the "new best score" steps are not in a row. If for example we have 50 steps in a row the solution cloning process will be executed 50 times. A smarter way would be to do the cloning process at the end of the sequence(only once).

Is this something that can be implemented easily or there is some other thing that would prevent it?

Another idea would be to do the cloning at every "new best score" step but only to clone the planning entity instances changed by the move selected as a step and append them to the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 50 steps in a row, and the first 23 steps improve the best solution, do we need to do a planning clone during that step 23 of that working solution?
Yes, we do, because there is no guarantee that any of the next 27 steps will improve the best score, so we don't want to loose the state of the solution at step 23. Not every step improves the best score, some go to a worse score (especially with Late Acceptance).

That being said, in Construction Heuristics - we actually don't do intermediate planning clones because we can guarantee that the solution will only improve (more initialized variables is always better).

In any case, the best way to make planning clones light is to design a model for which the planning entity class doesn't have any incoming references (except from the solution class of course)

Comment: Geoffrey i'm not sure you understood my point fully. The point with the 50 steps in a row was that each of them produce a "new best score" (we are 100% sure that the working solution is the best because of the calculated score) and at the 51st step this sequence is stopped by a worse score. What is done inside a step is a bunch of do and undo moves and then at the end the step itself. So the cloning could be done after the last undo move and before the step itself.

Comment: Even if there is a "pickEarly" option enabled ("FIRST_LAST_STEP_SCORE_IMPROVING" or FIRST_BEST_SCORE_IMPROVING) where only a do move is done, this would again work, because simply if the step would be made early it will again be a "new best score" step.

Comment: The second idea was to do the solution cloning in an "incremental" way (similar to incremental score calculation). Like incremental score calculation is working (first calculating the score for all the entities) we would (only once) clone the whole solution. Basically the clone after the construction heuristic. So at this point we would have a whole cloned solution produced and in local search when doing the step (which produces a "new best score") the entity instances from the move will be taken, cloned and updated in the whole cloned solution. The score will be updated also.

Comment: Also thank you for the note about the references, i definitely realized this after implementing custom cloning.

Comment: hmm, incrementally updating the best solution isn't a half bad idea. This will require `Move.rebase(ScoreDirector)` which I plan to add somewhere in the 7.x series for multithreaded incremental solving. The only downside is that it would break the best solution can be transferred to another thread guarantee, which is heavily used by anything that implements SolverEventListener and the future SolverManager...

Comment: Geoffrey would this be something that we should expect in a 7.x version?

Comment: It wouldn't be fair of me to commit to features in community, as my focus is mostly determined by RH customer priorities. That being said, presuming we don't do best solution events for the intermediate steps (so we don't risk race conditions by a user's listeners), this make a good jira. Please create a jira for it and link it here.

Comment: A little bit late but i created a jira and here is a link to it https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-818.